# How to get a list of directories and sub directories C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, directory

How would you get a list of all sub directories and their sub directories (until there are none left) from a root directory.

My current code uses a FolderBrowserDialog (WPF does not have one so I have to take it from winforms), and from there attempts to transverse directories. So far I can only make it transverse 1 level deep, as in

If the music directory is setup as

```
\rock\metallica\ride the lightning
\rock\aerosmith\
\rock\something\
```

and the user chooses \rock\ it would only grab files from aerosmith, something, and metallica, and not the sub directory of metallica, ride the lightning.

```
private void btnAddTestFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files;
    FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog();
    if (result.ToString() == "OK")
    {
        InitializePropertyValues();


        files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dlg.SelectedPath, "*.mp3");
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            lstvTrackList.Items.Add(new TrackList{ ID = lstvTrackList.Items.Count.ToString(), TrackName = Regex.Match(file, @".*\\(.*).mp3").Groups[1].Value, TrackPath = file });
        }

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dlg.SelectedPath);
        foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo d in di.GetDirectories())
        {
            files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(d.FullName, "*.mp3");
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                lstvTrackList.Items.Add(new TrackList{ ID = lstvTrackList.Items.Count.ToString(), TrackName = Regex.Match(file, @".*\\(.*).mp3").Groups[1].Value, TrackPath = file });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what I have attempted to do was first add all the loose files from the root directory, then get a list of directories inside the root directory and add those files.

I think I could figure it out if I knew how to crawl all sub directories starting from a root directory, but I don't quite understand how I would achieve that.

Does anyone have any hints, tips, or sample code that allows you to specify a root directory, then crawl every directory (keeping a string array) until no more sub directories are found, so I can grab files from each directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the sub directories you have to pass the [SearchOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as the third argument, Which will return all the sub-directories as well.

```
Directory.GetFiles("","",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

`SearchOption`

- **SearchOption.AllDirectories**: Includes the current directory and all its subdirectories in a search operation. This option includes reparse points such as mounted drives and symbolic links in the search.
- **SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly**: Includes only the current directory in
  a search operation.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the function was overloaded past the file filter. I feel kind of silly not looking at the function on msdn.